# NSCFString memory leak in Cocoa's animator proxy

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

After spending several hours on finding some leaking NSCFStrings in Instruments I seem to have realized that calling Cocoa's -animator proxy is causing this.

It is always reproducible: Just create a new Xcode project, add a new NSTableView in IB, fill it with some test data and run Instruments with Leaks. Once you hover over the NSTableView so that the scrollers fade in and out, you'll notice at least one leaking object in Instruments.

Although I've already filed a bug to Apple, can anyone confirm this leak?

Demo-Project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lszveuwrsuaxxg5/TableViewMemoryLeakStackOverflow.zip
Screencast: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vqtwbkus3jygdb3/ProxyAnimatorMemoryLeak.mov

Comment: What constitutes a leak to you?  I can't reproduce this on my machine.

Comment: Thank you for trying - have a look at the screencast I've just added. The quality doesn't seem to be good but one can clearly see the leaks in Instruments.

Comment: Hm, that's strange.  The leaks are coming from inside AppKit, but all those scroller methods do with strings is invoke `NSLog()`...

Comment: Instruments states that the leaking string is "overlayScrollerKnobAlpha" (6F766572 6C617953 63726F6C 6C65724B 6E6F6241 6C706861). The string is created using _NSPropertyNameFromSetter and that's where the CFString isn't released I guess?

Comment: Filed a bug: rdar://16822157

Answer (score 0):

This bug was resolved in OS X 10.9.3.